# How to post data with a ContentType of 'multipart/form-data' in Delphi REST?

Tags: rest, delphi, https, firemonkey, indy

I am trying to send a request to a REST API using `multipart/form-data` as the content type.

I always get "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Error" as a response.

I tried sending requests to methods that require `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and had success, though.

How can I achieve getting a success response from my API using `multipart/form-data`?

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
  strImageJSON : string;
  Input: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  Input := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
  Input.Clear;
  Input.AddFormField('Email', 'tugba.xx@allianz.com.tr');
  Input.AddFormField('Password', 'xxxx');
  RESTClient1 := TRESTClient.Create('http://192.168.1.172:81/');
  RESTRequest1 := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest1.Resource := 'api/Mobile/MobileLoginControl';
  RESTRequest1.AddBody(Input,TRESTContentType.ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
  RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  strImageJSON := RESTRequest1.Response.Content;
end;
```

Comment: maybe you got a solution in Indy that was why I tagged it. @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 4):

Embarcadero's REST component has its own built in `multipart/form-data` capabilities via the [`TRESTRequest.AddParameter()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddParameter) method:

```pascal
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
  strImageJSON : string;
begin
  RESTClient1 := TRESTClient.Create('http://192.168.1.172:81/');
  try
    RESTRequest1 := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    try
      RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
      RESTRequest1.Resource := 'api/Mobile/MobileLoginControl';
      RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Email', 'tugba.xx@allianz.com.tr', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);
      RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Password', 'xxxx', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkREQUESTBODY);
      RESTRequest1.Client := RESTClient1;
      RESTRequest1.Execute;
      strImageJSON := RESTRequest1.Response.Content;
    finally
      RESTRequest1.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RESTClient1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You don't need to use use Indy's `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`, especially when you are not using Indy's `TIdHTTP`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and saw that the content type was sent as 'multipart/formdata'. However when I check what I sent, it was just 'Password' which is the last parameter. I need to send 'Email' too. How can I send both of them? @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @RuhiGoktas and this is why I hate Embarcadero's REST framework. They over-complicated it and it doesn't actually work well. Do you have the same problem if you use `Params.AddItem()` instead of `AddParameter()`?

Comment: Tried that and got the same error. Actually the backend address uses https with TLS1.2. When it used http I was able to get success .

Comment: When it used http I was able to get success with TIdHttp. Should I upgrade something from somewhere? Or is there any different way I can get a response with?

Comment: Using `TIdHTTP`, you can enable TLS 1.2 in the SSLIOHandler's `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property.  I have no idea whether `TRESTClient` supports TLS 1.2 or not.