# with poDoNotEncode as a parameter option of my TCustomRESTRequest a '/' still get encoded to %2F

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to make a `POST` request using `TCustomRESTRequest`, to add more specific headers needed by the API I'm trying to reach.

As I'm adding headers to my request, I tried to add the specified `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`:

```
var
  RESTRequest : TCustomRESTRequest;
  RESTClient : TRESTClient;
  Response : TCustomRESTResponse;

begin
  RESTRequest := TCustomRESTRequest.create(nil);
  RESTClient := TRESTClient.create('');
  try
    RESTClient.BaseURL := 'urltoreach';
    RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('Content-Type','multipart/form-data',pkHTTPHEADER,poDoNotEncode);
    RESTRequest.Method := rmPOST;
    RESTRequest.Execute;
    Response := RESTRequest.Response;
    if Response.Status.Success then
      begin
        showmessage('success'); 
      end;
    else
      begin
        showmessage(Response.StatusText + ' : ' + Response.Content);
      end;
  finally
    RESTRequest.free;
    RESTClient.free;
  end;
end;
```

The problem I have is that I'm getting an error message:

> 'Unsupported media type : {"errors":"unsupported media type multipart%2Fform-data"}'

Meaning that my `/` is getting encoded even though I'm requesting `poDoNotEncode` as a parameter option.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: For "_Delphi developper since 12/09/2022_" you seem to have experience in other programming languages already. Judging by the all-lowercase parts I suppose you're not used to code completion of your IDE - but then why writing other methods and types case correctly?

Comment: The code i'm writing is going to be used in the company i work and get added to our documentation. So i need to be as precise as possible. But which all lowercase parts are you talking about ? the .create ones ?

Comment: Yes, and `showmessage` and `free`. It's inconsistent to the rest.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the precision, the former developpers all wrote showmessage and free in this lowercase form so i thought that was the way, sometimes create also was written in a all lowercase form sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for starters, you should be using `TRESTRequest` instead of `TCustomRESTRequest`.

But also, do not use `TRESTRequest.AddParameter(pkHTTPHEADER)` to set the HTTP `Content-Type` header.  `TRESTClient`/`TRESTRequest` will determine on their own which `Content-Type` to use based on the type of body content you are sending.

However, in your example, you are not actually posting any body content at all.  See [How to post data with a ContentType of 'multipart/form-data' in Delphi REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377996/) and [RESTRequest How to send a multipartformdata in a HTTP Post body?](https://community.embarcadero.com/component/easydiscuss/restrequest-how-to-send-a-multipartformdata-in-a-http-post-body?Itemid=1)

You need to add some body parameters.  `TRESTClient`/`TRESTRequest` will use `multipart/form-data` if one of the following conditions is met:

- there is a parameter using `ContentType = ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA` (not sure how you can set this, though)
- or, there are more than 1 parameter using `Kind = pkREQUESTBODY`
- or, there is 1 parameter using `Kind = pkREQUESTBODY`, and 1 or more parameters using `Kind = pkGETorPOST`

Comment: Ok Thank you for your explanations, i was trying to reach the api step by step by collecting and fixing the errors this is why i wasn't posting my body content yet.