# Issue posting JSON Data with REST AddBody method

Tags: rest, delphi

I'm having trouble with a `POST` request to an API which I am not the owner of.

The request must simply post JSON data. Please have a look:

```
var 
  RESTRequest : TRESTRequest;
  RESTClient : TRESTClient;
  Response : TRESTResponse;
  contract : TJSONObject;

begin
  RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('URL');
  try 
    RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
    try               
      contract := TJSONObject.Create;
      contract.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('name','my_first_contract.pdf'));
      
      RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
      RESTRequest.Method := rmPOST;
      RESTRequest.Accept := 'application/json';
      RESTRequest.AddParameter('j_token','mytoken',pkHTTPHEADER,poDoNotEncode);
      RESTRequest.AddBody(contract);
      RESTRequest.Execute;
      Response := RESTRequest.Response;
      ShowMessage(Response.StatusText + ' : ' + Response.Content);
  
    finally
      RESTRequest.Free;
    end;
  finally
    RESTClient.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

I obtained this error :

> Not Found : {"errors":"Fatal error in JsonConvert. Passed parameter json object in JsonConvert.deserializeObject() is not of type object.\n"}

I've read online that the `AddBody()` method first serializes its content if it's an object. In this case, the content of the body is my `TJSONObject`, but when I try to replace that with a `String`, like this:

```
var
  contract : String;
  ...
begin
  contract := '{"name":"my_first_contract.pdf"}';
  ...
  RESTRequest.AddBody(contract, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
  ...
end;
```

I'm getting the exact same error.

So, does that mean that a `TJSONObject` is not viewed as an Object for the `JsonConvert.deserializeObject()` method ? Or, is the serialization of the `AddBody()` messed up?

Comment: The code looks correct. Do you have an example of the content the API expects?

Comment: using directly the api swagger to modify data, we can see the curl its doing : 
curl -X 'POST' \
  'URL' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'j_token: mytoken' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "mon_premier_contrat.pdf"
}' 
does that help ?

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? I am a bit confused about the 4th parameter to `AddParameter`, which should be a set instead of an integer. You can try to replace it with `[poDoNotEncode]`.

Comment: I think it's Delphi 10.3 although i will still ask the lead developper when i see him. Using previous code written by my predecessors to learn delphi i saw them filling the last parameter with the integer 0 probably to avoid getting an error for not putting anything. I picked up the bad habit. When replacing it with poDoNotEncode the error doesn't change. With this integer as 4th parameter the request still work because else i would have gotten an error like 'j_token header required'.

Comment: IMHO, Embarcadero's REST components are not very well-designed. They have a lot of problems. If it wasn't for their cross-platform support, I would say never use them at all, period. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: I have updates : I set up my own api to see what headers i was posting with and i discovered that my 'j_token' value was getting encoded even though i specified the poDoNotEncode option to my AddParameter method. The '/' characters are all being encoded to %2F as well as the '|' getting encoded to %7C. In the end it's the same issue i had with this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73774548/with-podonotencode-as-a-parameter-option-of-my-tcustomrestrequest-a-still-ge 
But up to this day i still have no idea how to fix that encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the 'j_token' header : as I was trying to solve it, some friends wanted to help me but I didn't want to give them the access token because it's exclusive to my company. They still tried to access the api with a false token wich resulted with the same error as I was getting :

> Not Found : {"errors":"Fatal error in JsonConvert. Passed parameter json object in JsonConvert.deserializeObject() is not of type object.\n"}

Thanks to that I could deduce that the issue was on the j_token. After setting up my own api I could watch what was I posting and then I saw that my 'j_token' header was still getting encoded even though I added the `poDoNotEncode` options to my `AddParameter` method.

I created a new post on this forum to look for that poDoNotEncode error if you ever stumble upon this same problem  : [Trouble with poDoNotEncode option in TRESTRequest.AddParameter() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73867582/trouble-with-podonotencode)