# Trouble with poDoNotEncode option in TRESTRequest.AddParameter() method

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm having trouble using the `poDoNotEncode` option in the `TRESTRequest.AddParameter()` method. I need to be able to post a request with a `j_token` header with a value that includes the `'/'` characters or else. For this need, I read everywhere that I can simply add `poDoNotEncode` to the options of the request parameters.

I tried several methods I found on the Internet to add a `j_token` header to my request:

```
var 
  RESTRequest : TRESTRequest;
  RESTClient : TRESTClient;
  Response : TRESTResponse;
begin
  RESTClient := TRESTClient.Create('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
  RESTRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  try
    RESTRequest.Client := RESTClient;
    RESTRequest.Method := rmPOST;
    RESTRequest.AddParameter('j_token', 'ga/ga', pkHTTPHEADER, poDoNotEncode);
    //RESTRequest.Params.AddHeader('j_token', 'ga/ga').Options := poDoNotEncode;
    //RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('j_token', 'ga/ga', pkHTTPHEADER, poDoNotEncode);
    RESTRequest.Execute;
    Response := RESTRequest.Response;
    ShowMessage(Response.Content);
  finally
    RESTClient.Free;
    RESTRequest.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

In this example, I used my own API to see the content of my request headers (here just `j_token`). Each and every method I tried (the commented ones) result with this:

> Request headers : ga%2Fga

Meaning that the header I'm sending is url-encoded whether or not `poDoNotEncode` is specified.

Just to clarify, I'm working currently on a program developed by the company I work for. This software should use Delphi 10.3 Rio as its script language.

Maybe it can help, but when I try something like this:

```
RESTRequest.AddParameter('j_token', 'ga/ga', pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
```

I get this error:

> RUNTIME ERROR : Impossible converting variant of type (Array Variant) to type (Integer) when evaluating instruction PushVar($0,$0,$0,$0, 'Result')...

And when I try something like this:

```
RESTRequest.AddParameter('j_token', 'ga/ga', pkHTTPHEADER, TRESTRequestParameterOptions.poDoNotEncode);
```

then I get this error:

> Unknown identifier or variable is not declared : 'TRESTRequestParameterOptions'

I tried to be as precise as possible, because I'm completely stuck right now. If you need more precision, I'll try to answer as clearly as possible.

Comment: In your last example, try TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode (not Options)

Comment: it also says : Unknown identifier or variable is not declared : 'TRESTRequestParameterOption'

Comment: did you add RESTTypes to you uses clause? Also, wrap TRESTRequestParamterOption.poDoNotEncode in [ ]

Comment: We don't usually add uses clause to our code because it should already be in the software, when i tried to add it it said 'Library RESTTypes Not Found'. By wrapping TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode in brackets it doesn't change the error i'm getting

Comment: Sorry, try  REST.Types

Comment: It says that there is a Syntax error where the '.' is

Comment: This compiles just fine for me `RestRequest.AddParameter('j_token', 'ga/ga', pkHTTPHEADER, [TRESTRequestParameterOption.poDoNotEncode]);`

Comment: Are you executing the code as a script or do you compile it with Delphi? I ask because the set with [] is correct and the compiler should tell you that a simple poDoNotEncode is syntactically incorrect. It seems like your scripting engine has problems with the set.

Comment: The software i am on executes the code as a script. You must be right, the scripting engine might have some problems with that

Comment: Do you know if there exist an alternative to `poDoNotEncode`, like a function that could bypass the url encoding of the `RESTRequest.Execute` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem. To provide a context, I have access to the archives of my company with every script they made. To learn delphi it helps a lot, and as I was looking at an example for the `TRESTRequest.AddParameter()` method i noticed that the 4th parameter for this method was a 0 like this :

```
RESTRequest.AddParameter('j_token',mytoken,pkHTTPHEADER,0);
```

So I looked on the internet to find what that 0 meant and i found out it was supposed to be an option for the parameter such as `poDoNotEncode`. I was still wondering why they replaced that with a 0 but I simply guessed it was to avoid an error if you don't put anything because our compiler wants the `RESTRequest.AddParameter()` method to have 4 parameters. So in the end i started doing the same until i needed my parameter to not getting encoded. But the `poDoNotEncode` option wasn't working. I tried to see what it would show inside a `ShowMessage(poDoNotEncode);` and it showed me a 0. So I decided as a test to put a 1 instead of `poDoNotEncode` like this :

```
RESTRequest.AddParameter('j_token',mytoken,pkHTTPHEADER,1);
```

And finally it worked, I have no idea why our software prefers using Integers instead of the real options names but if ever you stumble upon this problem, there is a high chance that you had the same weird definition of options.

Thank you all for your help !

Comment: TRESTRequestParameterOption is an enumerated type (poDoNotEncode, poTransient, poAutoCreated, poFlatArray, poPhpArray, poListArray).  Enumerated types are zero indexed, so setting it to 1 sets it to poTransient.  In delphi, you can use enumerated types by name or by index.. so that should answer you mystery :)

Comment: Yeah i thought so when i read the embarcadero wiki again but it's kinda weird because if 0 was `poDoNotEncode` why would my request still gett encoded ?